# TV sci-fi show with strong female lead who looks after artifacts and also had Nikola Tesla in it

Tags: story-identification, tv, soft-sci-fi

I think it was in the 2000s, and the main lead is a strong woman who looks a bit like Lucy Lawless.

She, I seem to remember, had lived a long time and was good friends with Nikola Tesla, who dropped in from time to time. One of the characters is a guy who can change into a wolf, but he is deeply troubled by it.

The series revolves around a location, like a warehouse, that stores artifacts (not Warehouse 13) and so on.

Comment: As the multiple answers have already noted, all of your information seems to point to Sanctuary... *except* artifacts. Sanctuaries don't store artifacts, they keep *creatures* (some sapient, some not) safe. That said, Sanctuary and Warehouse 13 were running concurrently and on the same network, so perhaps you are conflating the two somewhat.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*[Sanctuary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanctuary_(TV_series))*

Features Nikola Tesla in seasons 2-4 and

> the talkative geek and lycanthrope Henry Foss (Ryan Robbins)

This [page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/Sanctuary) shows a poster for the program showing Amanda Tapping looking like Lucy Lawless.

> She heads the Sanctuary Network, which consists of large facilities
> known as "Sanctuaries" scattered throughout the world serving as safe
> havens for these "Abnormals".

The Sanctuaries would be the warehouse-like locations you mention.

Comment: Andrew shoots and scores! Thank you so much, this had been driving me crazy 

Answer (score 6):

That would be the [Sanctuary](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0965394/) with [Amanda Tapping](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0850102) in the leading role as [Dr. Helen Magnus](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0965394/characters/nm0850102), a long living (centuries) scientist working with extraordinary people and researching creatures. There is a bigfoot or the mentioned werewolf living in the Sanctuary working together with Dr. Magnus, meeting other fantastic beings like vampires, famous persons like Nikola Tesla or Jack The Ripper and many other.

Additional info: https://sanctuary.fandom.com/wiki/The_Sanctuary_Network

Answer (score 6):

Probably, **Sanctuary**. A 2008 TV show with Amanda Tapping as the strong female lead; Dr. Helen Magnus, she has longevity, due to an injection of vampire blood.  She runs a sanctuary, a warehouse type  of facility, one of many around the world. Assisted by Nicola Tesla and werewolf: Henry Foss